# bind9 internal domain name

Tags: router, bind

For our internal network we're using domain names like `user.int`. I've setup bind to resolve those to the appropriate IP addresses.

Since `.int` is actual top-level domain name(although used for just a few sites: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.int), I'd like real domains like http://nato.int/ to be resolved properly.

I've chosen `.int` domain because browsers understand that it's a domain when you type *whatever.int* in the address bar and don't send you to search engine results page.

Here is my zone file:

```
$TTL 38400
int.    IN      SOA     myrouter. (
                        1329153712
                        10800
                        3600
                        604800
                        38400 )
int.    IN      NS      myrouter.

user       IN      A       192.168.2.123
```

As far as I understand the start of authority(SOA) here is my router, so it won't relay requests for anything in `.int` zone to another DNS server.

Is there a fix for this behavior apart from mirroring all public domain names in my local configuration on daily basis?

Comment: Don't do this. Use a subdomain of your actual domain name.

Comment: Are there other implications that I haven't faced yet, apart from the one described in my question? Or is it just a wrong approach?

Comment: The latter one. Use .local if you really need local TLD.

Comment: If you're worried about having to type a long domain name, you can always set the search path for DNS resolution to the subdomain you choose. For example, if you set up fred.internal.emilm.com in BIND and set the search internal.emilm.com on your internal clients (perhaps by dhcp or group policy), http:// fred / should work just as you expect.

Comment: @EugeneM.Zheganin `.local` is reserved for mdns use, though. So using that can cause other conflicts instead.